# How do I calculate the area of a triangle intersecting a cylinder?

Tags: geometry, area

I have a cylinder and a triangle in 3D space. Both can be arbitrarily positioned, oriented, and sized. I would like to know the area of the triangle that is intersecting the volume described by the cylinder.

What I have determined thus far:

- It's beneficial to first translate and rotate the cylinder such that its centre is at the origin, and orientation aligned with the z-axis, applying the same transformation on the triangle.
- It can be possible to reduce the problem to a 2D one by using the plane described by the triangle as a cutting plane for the cylinder. This could result in a triangle intersecting an oval, an oval cut off with a straight line at either end, or in some cases a rectangle.
- If I take a plane orthogonal to the symmetry axis of the cylinder and intersect that plane with the triangle I either end up with a line segment or the entire triangle wherever that plane intersects both the triangle and cylinder. In the case of the line segment, the area could be expressed as a sum integral, or as a 2D triangle-circle area overlap problem otherwise.
- While I'm not sure if this would work, if I do the transformation listed in point 1 and project the cylinder and triangle on to the x-y plane, I can use a 2D intersection algorithm to determine the intersecting area, then use the ratio between the 3D triangle's area and 2D triangle's area to determine the 3D intersecting area.

But this is basically where my capabilities with this kind of problem end.

For my purposes I can estimate this area by taking a large quantity of random point samples on the triangle, doing some relatively simple point-cylinder intersection tests for each of them, and counting the points that do. However, I was hoping to find a more analytical way, but have not managed to proceed further than what I have listed above.

Comment: Is this an infinite cylinder, or a finite length one?

Without loss of generality, you can place the origin at the center of the cylinder with one of the axes along the cylinder and transform the triangle to this CSYS.

Comment: If the triangle intersects the top or bottom cap of the cylinder the problem becomes a tad more complex.

Comment: This is a finite length cylinder.

Comment: This is indeed a very complicated problem.  But there is a very simple numerical solution, if you use the Monte Carlo method.  So you just place a large number of points inside the entire triangle.  The points should be placed along parallel lines that are equally spaced and parallel to the three sides of the triangle.  Count the total number of points, then count the number of points that are inside the cylinder.  The required area is then equal to the area of the triangle times the ratio of the number of points inside the cylinder to the total number of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is addressed here

> https://www.geometrictools.com/Samples/Intersection.html#IntersectTriangleCylinder

or rather, the related problem of finding the intersection between a cylinder and a triangle.

> [image: scr]

There are many edge cases to consider, each requiring its own mathematical description and it would be beyond the scope of an answer in this site to cover all the cases.

> [image: scr2]

A more detailed description of this situation is described in this paper below:

> https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionTriangleCylinder.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comment above, I show below how to sample the triangle, generating "equally spaced" points.

Suppose the vertices of the triangle are $A, B, C$, then compute vector

$ V = A B = B - A $

and

$ W = A C = C - A $

Segment $V$ into $n$ equally spaced intervals, and segment $W$ into $n$ equally spaced intervals.

For $i = 0 \text{ to } n$ and $j = 0 \text{ to } (n - i)$

$P_{ij} = A + \left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right) V + \left( \dfrac{j}{n} \right) W$

Clearly $P_{ij}$ are parallel to $V=AB$ for increasing $i$ and constant $j$ and parallel to $W = AC$ for increasing $j$ and constant $i$.

If $r_1 = \dfrac{i}{n} , r_2 = \dfrac{j}{n} $ and $ r_1 + r_2 = r $, where $r$ is constant, then

$ P_{ij} = A + r_1 V + r_2 W = A + r_1 (B - A) + r_2 (C - A) = (1 - r_1 - r_2) A + r_1 A + r_2 C $

And this simplifies to

$ P_{ij} = (1 - r) A + r_1 B + (r - r_1) C = (1 - r) A + r C + r_1 (B - C) $

So $P_{ij}$ will be parallel to $BC$.  Note that this condition is equivalent to $i+j =k \le n$.

The total number of points is

$ N = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^{n} \sum_{j = 0 }^{n - i} 1 \\
= \sum_{i = 0}^{n} (n - i + 1)  \\
= (n + 1)(n +1 ) -  \dfrac{1}{2} (n)(n+1) ) \\
= \dfrac{1}{2} ( n + 1 ) (n + 2 )$

Hence, the total number of points is

$ N = \dfrac{1}{2} ( n + 1 )(n + 2)$

Now for each of the points $P_{ij}$ we want to check if it is inside the cylinder.  Without applying any transformation to the cylinder, let's assume that the axis of the cylinder is along unit vector $a$, its radius is $r$, its center is point $C$, and its length is $L$.  We can build a reference frame with its $z$ axis parallel to the vector $a$, and with its origin at the center of the cylinder $C$.

To create this reference frame, find any a unit vector $u_1$ that is perpendicular to $a$, and define $u_2 = a \times u_1 $, then define the rotation matrix

$ R = [ u_1, u_2, a ] $

Now a world frame point $p$ is related to a corresponding cylinder point $q$ as follows

$ p = C + R q $

From which it follows that the coordinates of any point with respect to the cylinder frame is

$ q = R^{-1} (p - C) = R^T (p - C) $

Point $p$ will be inside the cylinder only if

$ | q_z | \le \dfrac{L}{2} $

and

$ q_x^2 + q_y^2 \le r^2 $

If these two conditions are satisfied then the point is inside, otherwise it is outside.

What is left is to count the number of point that are inside.  Let's call this N_i, then the area of the triangle that is inside the cylinder is

$ A_{\text{inside}} = \left(\dfrac{N_i}{N} \right) [ABC] $

where $[ABC]$ denotes the area of $\triangle ABC$.